# Exception doesn't show filename in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel and trying to develop a small site. I'm using laravel 5.1 on Debian Jessie on a vm, running php 5.6. I've made a mistake somewhere in the code, and when I load the page, I get this error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in 6ca7e2ffd061baf9fd48533797a8e004 line 36: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

    in 6ca7e2ffd061baf9fd48533797a8e004 line 36
    at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
    at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
    at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
    ...
```

I'm supposing that `6ca7e2ffd061baf9fd48533797a8e004` is a cached or compiled version of some php file, but I can't obviously tell which one. How can I troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Mark as answer if that helped you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here are the steps that I always do to check this kid of errors.

1. If you have sublime text, try to hit `ctrl+p` and paste `6ca7e2ffd061baf9fd48533797a8e004` inside.
2. You will get to a file that looks very much similar to the one of the blade files that you already have but it won't have any blade syntax.
3. Try to hit `ctrl+g` and then type `36` in it. It will get you to that line. And yes, error is wither on one line top or one line below that 36th line.

If possible please paste that lines so that I can review and tell you the accurate answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, silly me, I did a `find` and it looks like blade makes rendered caches in `storage/framework/views/`. That doesn't directly tell me which template it is, but from looking inside the file, I can figure it out.

In these renders, all of the `@yield` and `{!! !!}` are expanded in to inline php code.